# c++ Linked List with priority queue

Tags: c++

I trying to code out the Linked List with priority queue and i encountered some problem.

I have about 7 priority from 1 the most to 7 the least important.

here's my current insert method.

```
void queue::addToQueueList(int newPriority, double newFare, int custID)
{
    node* newnode= new node;
    newnode->priority= newPriority;
    newnode->fare = newFare;
    newnode->cusID = custID;
    newnode->next= NULL;

    if (isempty())
    {
        front = back = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        node* temp = front;
        if(newnode->priority < temp->priority)
        {
            newnode->next = front;
            front = newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            while(newnode->priority < temp->priority)
            {
                if(temp->next == NULL)
                {
                    break;
                    temp = temp->next;
                }
            }
            if(temp->next == NULL && newnode->priority < temp->priority)
            {
                back->next = newnode;
                back = newnode;
            }
            else
            {
                newnode->next = temp->next;
                temp->next = newnode;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Invoked as:

```
qList->addToQueueList(2, 488.88, A);
qList->addToQueueList(1, 388.88, B);
qList->addToQueueList(3, 488.88, C);
```

Expected result should be :

```
B, A, C
```

THe result shows :

```
B, C, A
```

Comment: I think you misplaced the assignment in the loop.

Comment: Also, for such a short list as in your example, then you could easily step through the code line by line in a debugger, to see what's really happening.

Comment: The `back` pointer in a priority queue seems pointless. Not sure why you even have one.

Comment: For only 7 priorities, I would probably just make an array/vector of 7 list instances.

Comment: @MartinJames agreed. If the priority count is indeed fixed and sequential, and the OP seems to use strictly less-than for insertion, a push to the head of a `priorities[n-1]` pointer array, where `n` is in `{1..7}` would be *very* fast; O(1). No link-walking whould be needed on insertion whatsoever.

Comment: Im required to use linked list for this case. 

and I dont understand what ur explanation, WhozCraig.

Comment: @StevenMeowDeClaude it means just keep 7 linked lists in an array; `node *priorities[7];` one list for each priority. the insertion complexity would be constant O(1), the extraction complexity O(7) (also constant). It is a luxury to have fixed priority rankings, and in this case that luxury could be exploited. It is only somewhat related to your posted question, just an observation on Martin's part for an alternative implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Your making this considerably harder than it needs to be. Ultimately you need to walk the list, find the insertion point, remember how you arrived at that insertion point, and wire *both* your fore and aft pointers appropriately. Also a priority queue has no reason to keep a "back" pointer, so I'm not sure why you have one.

There are a number of ways to do this. First, to make the code cleaner to understand, providing a proper parameterized constructor for `node` is both trivial and helpful:

```
struct node
{
    int priority;
    double fare;
    int cusID;
    node *next;

    node(int p, double f, int id, node *nxt = nullptr)
        : priority(p), fare(f), cusID(id), next(nxt)
    {
    }
};
```

One you have that, you can go down the road you were apparently trying to navigate, using a pointer-value list walking approach. To do that you need to maintain a previous pointer:

```
void queue::addToQueueList(int newPriority, double newFare, int custID)
{
    node* temp = front, *prev = NULL;
    while (temp && temp->priority < newPriority)
    {
        prev = temp;         // remember how we got here
        temp = temp->next;   // advance to next node
    }

    // create new node, linking to temp
    node *newnode = new node(newPriority, newFair, custID, temp);

    // link to previous node or assign as new head, whichever is needed
    if (prev != nullptr)
        prev->next = newnode;
    else
        head = newnode;

    // though there is no need for a back pointer in a priority queue
    //  you had one none-the-less, so....
    if (!temp)
        back = newnode;
}
```

it is worth noting that this algorithm will insert new arrivals with similar priority at the *head* of that priority section of the list. I.e. the newest arrivals for a given priority are always at the forefront of that priority's position in the queue. If you want the *oldest* arrivals of a given priority to be "ahead" of their brethren, you simply need to change this:

```
while (temp && temp->priority < newPriority)
```

to this:

```
while (temp && temp->priority <= newPriority)  // note < is now <=
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison in your while loop is wrong. When inserting `C` `newnode->priority == 3` and `temp(B)->priority == 1`. Thus the while loop is never entered.

Also, the `temp = temp->next` inside the while loop should be outside (after) the if statement. Otherwise this will be an infinite loop.

Assuming you are correcting these: you will always insert the new element **after** temp. Be aware of this in your fix of your comparisons. You are likely to add comparisons with `temp->next->priority` as well.

I agree with Joachim in the comments: step through the code with a debugger. Then you can see the values of the variables and which comparisons produce which results.